# Mongo group by query convert into java

Tags: java, mongodb

How should I convert below mongo query in java, I used mongo java driver

```
db.demo.aggregate([
// Unwind the array
{ "$unwind": "$iInfo" },

// Sort the array elements within documents
{ "$sort": { "_id": -1, "iInfo.ifout": -1 } },

// Take only the "first" array element per document
{ "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "Iifout": { "$first": "$iInfo.ifout" },
    "Iiferror": { "$first": "$iInfo.iferror" },
    "Iifdes": { "$first": "$iInfo.ifdes" },
    "Iifin": { "$first": "$iInfo.ifin" }
}},

// Group to push those results as an array
{ "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "iInfo": {
        "$push": {
            "ifout": "$Iifout",
            "iferror": "$Iiferror",
            "Iifdes": "$Iifdes",
            "Iifin": "$Iifin"
        }
    }
}}
])
```

I write java code as below but it not work properly

```
BasicDBObject cmdBody = new BasicDBObject("aggregate",
            collectionRealtime.toString());
        pipeline.add(new BasicDBObject("$limit", 10));
        pipeline.add(new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "$iInfo"));
        pipeline.add(new BasicDBObject("$sort", new BasicDBObject(
            "iInfo.ifout", -1)));
        cmdBody.put("pipeline", pipeline);
```

when I run above java code it shows me all my nested output with sort but not shows in group and limit not work it display all documents.

Comment: This really is not hard. It's just constructing `BasicDBObject` items and adding them to a "List" form, or as separate arguments. Your attempt here does not really try. You can always `System.out.println` or other better logging to see what you have constructed. Really, just give it a go before asking someone to write "copy/paste" code for you.

Comment: Another hint for "good" practice here. Don't use the code gleaned from an answer you have not accepted yet as a means to post another question. The answer you are referencing actually solves your problem even though you are still working out your Java coding. You could have always asked the person posting the answer for a specific Java example. Oh wait, that was me.